# polygon enable drawing in google maps API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a replacement for polyline/polygon enableDrawing() , disableEditing() in google maps API v3?Can some one please share a sample code for the same?

Comment: [google.maps.Polyline.setEditable](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline) - [google.maps.Polygon.setEditable](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon) - [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#editable)

Answer (score 0):

I found a example with API.v2. Maybe help you: http://salman-w.blogspot.com.br/2011/03/zoom-to-fit-all-markers-on-google-map.html

Comment: Hi actually I am looking for some sample code in v3.Is there in any library available for polyline / polygon enabledrawing